# How to get real width td table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I create one table in html and this `table` width is 988 px and `tr` width is 100% `table` width.

In table tag exist 5 `td` tag that this `td` tag width 20%.

When I get with these tags with jQuery (`td` tag) show me in console this :

```
198 
197 
198 
197 
198
```

but I see this tags width in console **197.59**.

I want get this value not these 197 or 198.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More precise than `element.offsetWidth` is:

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

it shows exact width as rendered by the browser.

MDN reference: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that if you're using jQuery - you know javascript. In jquery that would be: `$('table td')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width`. You can read more in the reference link I gave you.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers won't use **fractionnal pixels** as a unit when **showing specs** to you. The smallest unit is a whole pixel to them.

### Why?

Set an element with a `position:relative` CSS attribute. Relative to the whole document, the element will be positioned at some really precise values, but those are rounded up at the pixel unit since it wouldn't make sense to show `left:145.21542258854755124554px` for every positioning value.

**You can see those values when you drag elements and track their actual position**.

---

**But:** ***[Browsers still read fractional pixels](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#length-units)***. (*W3C*)

**Note:** In the demo, if you zoom in close enough, you **will see a difference** between the two colored `div` elements, even though there's a **0.4px** difference.

#### zoomed at 400% - 0.4px difference:

[image: zoomed at 400% - 0.4px difference.]

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/VDqHw/)

#### Output:

```
196px 195px 195px 195px 195px
```

---

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="int">a</div>
<div id="float">a</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');


for (var td in tds) {
    if (tds[td].nodeType == 1) 
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += parseFloat(tds[td].offsetWidth,10) + "px";
}
```

### CSS

```
table {
    width: 988px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
tr {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
td {
    width:20%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#int {
    width:21px;
    background-color:red;
}  
#float {
    width:21.4px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, that's how the page is rendering them, so that is what jQuery will report. You can't have .59 of a pixel, so it will generate the `<td>`s to round to an integer, causing them to differ by a pixel as you've seen. You could consider adding them all up and averaging them? Otherwise, have a look at what the DOM reports.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tblW = parseInt($('table').css('width'), 10);
var tdW = new Number(0.20);
var pxtdW =  tblW * tdW;
alert(pxtdW);
```