# Actual height of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a regular html table located inside a div. The div's width is 70%, so the table resizes too. The thing is, as it shrinks, there are some line-breaks, making the table 'taller' than the div. 
In order to make a javascript function to change the font-size of the specific table tds that may break lines, I wanted to compare both heights of the table and its div.

However, using JQuery's `.height()` and `.outerHeight()` return me the height they were assigned in the css, not their *actual* height. If I got at least the height of the overflown area, it would be great already. Any guesses on what to try?

PS: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838603/how-to-get-real-width-td-table) method, but it didn't work out either.

EDIT: Here is a very simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqdkqng0/1/), just so you understand how it is nested.

I appreciate the suggestions given, but they didn't work either.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Offset properties belong to the element themselves.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('#table').offsetHeight;
```

Here is some documentation on offset values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements.

For the most part, this will give you the dimensions of the space that's being taken up on the screen. If you want the dimensions including overflow, then the scroll dimensions that @NielsKeurentjes provided would be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollHeight`, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rnfn37sz/2/).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight):

> The `Element.scrollHeight` read-only attribute is a measurement of the
>   height of an element's content, including content not visible on the
>   screen due to overflow. The `scrollHeight` value is equal to the minimum
>   `clientHeight` the element would require in order to fit all the content
>   in the viewpoint without using a vertical scrollbar. It includes the
>   element padding but not its margin.